# Real-world illustration of discontinuity in $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Let $f:A\in\mathbb R^2\rightarrow  B\in\mathbb R^2$ and $(x_0,y_0)\in A$ be a point of discontinuity of $f$ s.t. $lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(x_0,y_0)} f(x,y)$ doesn't exist uniquely. What is a real life example of such a situation?
I thought that projecting an image of an object on the screen via projector is a good example of such a mapping but I wonder how to visualize the points of discontinuity (if any) in this example? May be, an image with a *scratch/white spot/blur/distortion* for $f(x_0,y_0)$?

If there exists a more suitable example for this, then please help me to visualize it.

**Edit**: My aim is to visualize a complex mapping and I know that one way is through the visualization of a mapping from $\mathbb R^2$ to itself, so if possible, can someone please give a possible way of visualization of a complex function?

Answer (score 2):

Sweep a laser beam--left/right and up/down--across a complex three-dimensional scene, such as trees in a forest or furniture in a home.  The location of the spot jumps discontinuously.  Then image the three-dimensional scene with a camera off to the side, so that each point in the scene leads to a point on the two-dimensional sensor of the camera.  Hence we have a discontinuous mapping from the $\mathbb R^2$ laser projection space to the $\mathbb R^2$ space on the camera sensor.

Comment: Thanks for your example. But is it possible to have a discontinuous function taking $\mathbb R^2 directly as the first source?